# SQL DB2 query with where clause

Tags: db2

Can you please help me out with the below query?

I need to extract from column `VAL_DT` only items with date older than today's date but this rule should not apply to items that contain the following wordings in column `MVT_DS`: "NOSTRO", "SCREV", "SCRIN", "MAN".

here is my attempt

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE VAL_DT < CURRENT DATE  IF MVT_DS <> 'NOSTRO' AND MVT_DS <> 'SCREV' AND MVT_DS <> 'SCRIN' AND MVT_DS <> 'MAN'
```

Comment: `IF` is invalid in the `WHERE` clause. See if you can use the logical `OR` somehow.

Answer (score 3):

I would amend your logic to:

```
WHERE 
    VAL_DT < CURRENT DATE 
    OR 
    (
        MVT_DS = 'NOSTRO' 
        OR MVT_DS = 'SCREV' 
        OR MVT_DS = 'SCRIN' 
        OR MVT_DS = 'MAN'
    )
```

or even

```
WHERE 
    VAL_DT < CURRENT DATE 
    OR MVT_DS IN (
      'NOSTRO', 'SCREV', 'SCRIN', 'MAN'
    )
```

I changed it so that *VAL_DT* should be earlier than the current date or the other field should equal the respective values. So to get a "true" result - either *VAL_DT* < "current date" or *MVT_DS* is one of those values. If it's one of those values it will therefore bypass the "current date" check, effectively.