# SQL db2 remove specific item from the query

Tags: db2, excel

Can you please help me out with the below query?
What I am looking for is a code to exclude items with wording '90003' from column COR_ID.
So far I have a code that extracts data with date older than today from column VAL_DT, excluding items with wordings MAN, NOSTRO, SCREV and SCRIN for which query shows also dates newer than today.

All I need is for the below code is to remove '90003' from column COR_ID

```
WHERE 
    VAL_DT < CURRENT DATE AND COR_ID <> '90003'
    OR (   
       MVT_DS = 'NOSTRO' 
       OR MVT_DS = 'SCREV' 
       OR MVT_DS = 'SCRIN'
       OR MVT_DS = 'MAN' 
       )
```

Comment: Are you using db2, another DBMS, or excel?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with your current query? By the way, you seem to have used the solution provided for [your previous question]( http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/132530/sql-db2-query-with-where-clause) ; please consider marking the useful answer as accepted.

Comment: I thought I have accepted the answer from previous question. I was advised by administrator to open a new question as my last question was not fully explained. The missing part is that I need to remove all items worded '90003' from entire query. I am downloading data from DB2 to excel

Comment: Do you want to exclude COR_ID = '90003' from the entire result set or just fronm the part where val_dt < current date?    I also suggest in the query above to use " or MVT_DS in ('NOSTRO', 'SCREV', 'SCRIN', 'MAN') " which makes it mich more readable....

Comment: I need to remove all 90003 whether older or newer than today ... any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following WHERE clause shold do the job

```
WHERE COR_ID <> '90003'
  AND (VAL_DT < CURRENT DATE  OR MVT_DS in ('NOSTRO', 'SCREV', 'SCRIN', 'MAN')  )
```

Comment: hello, I have copied and pasted the code run it and got error message. Nothing queried. Can you please check? Thank you

Comment: maybe the second closing bracket is the problem - I just saw it and corrected it

Comment: works perfectly thank you. How I can give you a point?

Comment: great :-) -  mark it as answer